# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

When I use firebase auth in my project
I've got this error

> com.example.blooms_broccoli, PID: 7900
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property auth has not been initialized

this is what error start

```
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class Auth: MultiDexApplication() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
        var email: String? = null

        fun checkAuth(): Boolean {
            var currentUser = auth.currentUser
            email = currentUser?.email
            return currentUser?.isEmailVerified ?: false
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        auth = Firebase.auth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UninitializedPropertyAccessException`

> Exception occurs when you use `lateinit` property before initializing it.

In your case you initialized `lateinit` `auth` property in `onCreate` method and used in function `checkAuth()` of companion object.

Make sure you access `auth` after initializing it.
To avoid this crash you can use `isInitialized` condition

```kotlin
if(::auth.isInitialized) {
    var currentUser = auth.currentUser
    email = currentUser?.email
    return currentUser?.isEmailVerified ?: false
}
```

From where are you calling `checkAuth()` function and where you declared your `Auth : MultiDexApplication()` Application class?